# R How to split one column into multiple

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe where one column shows hour type and another shows number of hours, but I want it to be a dataframe where each hour type has its own column.

Like from this:

```
name   hourtype   hours 

Amy       A         3
Amy       B         2   
Bob       B         1   
Bob       C         4
Cam       A         5
Cam       B         1
Cam       C         1
Dan       A         2
```

To this:

```
name   A   B   C

Amy    3   2   0
Bob    0   1   4   
Cam    5   1   1
Dan    2   0   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Your issue is mainly to the format of data. You have data in long format so you want now in wide format. The function `pivot_wider()` from `tidyr`, a `tidyverse` package can help with that. After this, you can set `NA` values to zero with `replace`. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = hourtype,values_from=hours) %>%
  replace(is.na(.),0)
```

The output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  name      A     B     C
  <chr> <int> <int> <int>
1 Amy       3     2     0
2 Bob       0     1     4
3 Cam       5     1     1
4 Dan       2     0     0
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(name = c("Amy", "Amy", "Bob", "Bob", "Cam", "Cam", 
"Cam", "Dan"), hourtype = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", 
"A"), hours = c(3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```